# How do I animate a View outside of parent scroll view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to increase the size of a rounded rectangle to fill the screen when it is tapped but it is inside of a scroll view.

```
struct ReviewView : View {
    var ratings: [Rating] = []
    @State var isZoomed = false

    var body: some View {
        return ScrollView {
            HStack {
                ForEach(ratings) { rating in
                    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                            .frame(width: self.isZoomed ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width : 200)
                            .animation(.spring())
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(String(repeating: "☆", count: 5-rating.rating) + String(repeating: "★", count: rating.rating))
                                .font(.body)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 150, maxHeight: 40, alignment: .topLeading)
                                .padding(.top, 5)
                            Text(rating.ratingTitle)
                                .font(.callout).bold()
                                .lineLimit(2)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 150, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 45, alignment: .topLeading)
                            Text(rating.ratingDescription)
                                .font(.footnote)
                                .lineLimit(3)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 150, alignment: .topLeading)

                        }.padding(.leading, 10)
                         .padding(.top, 5)
                         .tapAction { self.isZoomed.toggle() }
                    }
                }
                PresentationButton(destination: RatingsView()) {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 150)
                        Text("View More")
                    }
                }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with my code is that all of the rectangles extend. How should I get the specific rectangle and extend that to the view size outside the scroll view?

---

**Edit:**

I have tried adding an `isZoomed` property to my ratings struct so it looks like this:

```
struct Rating : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let ratingTitle, ratingDescription: String
    let rating: Int
    var isZoomed: Bool = false
}
```

I then have an array of ratings like this:

```
let ratingsExample = [Rating(ratingTitle: "Great!", ratingDescription: "example", rating: 4), Rating(ratingTitle: "Bad!", ratingDescription: "example", rating: 1)]
```

And the view is called with the above array:

```
ReviewView(ratings: ratingsExample)
```

How do I change the value of the `isZoomed` property of my struct and make it render the view again when it is changed, just like a state? Is this possible?

---

**Edit 2:**

I have successfully worked out how to only zoom one rectangle. I did this by making the `id` an `Int` and ordering the ratings in the test data like this:

```
struct Rating : Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let ratingTitle, ratingDescription: String
    let rating: Int
}

let ratingsExample = [Rating(id: 0, ratingTitle: "Good", ratingDescription: "good example", rating: 5), Rating(id: 1, ratingTitle: "bad", ratingDescription: "bad example", rating: 1)]
```

Added a state variable in the view as a array of Booleans:

```
@State var isZoomed: [Bool]
```

Added a function to work out current number of ratings, add them to a `Bool` array as `false`:

```
func isZoomedList(ratings: [Rating]) -> [Bool] {
    var isZoomed: [Bool] = []
    for _ in ratings {
        isZoomed.append(false)
    }
    return isZoomed
}
```

Call the view with the function and assign that as the `@State` which can then be changed within the view:

```
ReviewView(ratings: ratingsExample, isZoomed: isZoomedList(ratings: ratingsExample))
```

Now the `.tapAction` only changes the specific rectangles by specifying the `id`:

```
.tapAction { self.isZoomed[rating.id].toggle() }
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but it works just fine.

#### The thing that still isn't working is that the rectangle still only expands within the scroll view and looks like this:

[image: extendinscrollview]

#### How do I extend over the screen, outside the scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

Every rectangle is independent of their tap. But you are using `isZoomed` State var for all the rectangles. So whenever you're tapping a rectangle `isZoomed` got toggled and this `isZoomed` is used by all the rectangles, so they will change their frame accordingly.
Solution is you need to keep an array of `isZoomed` State var, and update the specific rectangle that got tapped. This will be sufficient to extend the only specific rectangle.

```swift
var ratings: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    @State var isZoomed: [Bool] = [false, false, false, false]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                ForEach(ratings) { rating in
                    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                            .frame(width: self.isZoomed[rating] ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width : 200, height: self.isZoomed[rating] ? UIScreen.main.bounds.height : 150)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                            .animation(.spring())
                        }.tapAction { self.isZoomed[rating].toggle() }
                }
            }.padding()
        }
```

About the second query, As per my knowledge (Please correct me if I am wrong), by default **scrollView's** frame is set to `UIScreen.main.bounds` (doesn't ignore the **safe area**). You are expanding the rectangle to `UIScreen.main.bounds` which is the borderline for **scrollView frame**.